# Python Differentiate mistake

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm writing a program that reads in two proteins of the same (string) length and returns how many of the amino acid letters are different. I managed to write the some of the bits but unfortunately couldn't complete all of it so can any please guide through this by having a look on my code:

```
a = raw_input("Cheetah protein: ")
b = raw_input("Domestic cat protein: ")
u=zip(a,b)
d=dict(u)
x = 1
for i,j in d.items(): 
    if i == j:
        x = x + 1   
print x
```

This the output I want to produce:

```
Cheetah protein: IGADKYFHARGNYDAA
Domestic cat protein: KGADKYFHARGNYEAA
2 difference(s).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a="IGADKYFHARGNYDAA"
b="KGADKYFHARGNYEAA"

u=zip(a,b)          
x = 0               # not 1
for i,j in u:       # you don't need a dict here
    print i,j, 
    if i != j:      # they differ iff they are not equal to each other
        x = x + 1
        print "  neq" 
    else:
        print " eq"  
print x
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should describe better what you are trying to achieve. I don't understand this check:

```
if i == j:
```

If you want to check the differences, you should write instead:

```
if i != j:
```

After this fix your code gives me 3 differences for your example with cat and cheetah - are you sure the example is correct?

**EDIT**: OK, I see you're counting differences starting from one. Change the line

```
x = 1
```

to

```
x = 0
```

I don't think you want to assume that there is always at least one difference ;-)

Comment: yeah u can check it by ur self by comparing both of them

Answer (score 0):

```
func=lambda x,y: ((x!=y) and 1) or 0
print sum(map(func, a,b)), 'difference(s)'
```

Comment: The and/or trick is incredibly outdated, and hardly any more clear than just using the arithmetic value of `x != y`. Also, it's simpler to just use a generator expression rather than invoking `map`.

Comment: @Karl, what make the and/or trick incredibly outdated ? I feel it's handy expression, rather than a if-self statement. Also, what make a generator expression simpler(and more straightforward) than a map ?

Answer (score 0):

Different proteins has different amino acids sequences ("letters"), but has also different lengths. No answers take care of this because you didn't asked for. Answering your question:

```
>>> a="IGADKYFHARGNYDAA"
>>> b="KGADKYFHARGNYEAA"
>>> sum(1 for x, y in zip(a,b) if x!=y)
2
```

I used "generator expressions" to generate a number one for each pair of different amino acids and summed up. Now if you want to spot the changed amino acids using a similar method:

```
>>> diff = ''.join('-' if x==y else y for x, y in zip(a,b))
>>> print 'A:', a, '\nB:', diff
A: IGADKYFHARGNYDAA
B: K------------E--
```